# macOS Sierra Public Beta 2 stuck at downloading

Tags: mac-appstore, software-update

I have installed first public beta yesterday. Now App Store says there is a second update to public beta. There is no problem with network or internet at all but somehow update stucks at 0 bytes and no progress. Any suggestions to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Best not to delete a duplicate - they help the site point people to the main post when searching for a specific version.